# Estimote Repeat Notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, estimote

I am developing an iOS 8 app with multiple Estimote iBeacons. According to (https://community.estimote.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200966066-How-detect-multiple-beacons-iOS?locale=en-us), I implemented one BeaconManager, and registered it with two BeaconRegions. However, only the second beacon region works.

Instead, I used two BeaconManagers and register one BeaconRegion for each of them. Now it works. However, a new problem occurs: in some cases when I enter or exit the region, I receive multiple notifications for one beacon, instead of only one. This link (http://beekn.net/2013/11/ibeacon-tutorial-dealing-with-errors/) says it's a bug from Apple, but I am not sure about the case.

Anyone can help?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beacon regions are shared system resources, which means that **all** the BeaconManagers and LocationManagers are notified about state changes of **all** the regions registered in the app.

Example: if you monitor beacon region A with manager A, and beacon region B with manager B, manager A will still get notifications about region B. Same for manager B and region A.

Because of that, it rarely makes sense to have more than one instance of a BeaconManager in your app.

Monitoring multiple regions should work just fine with a single BeaconManager, there must be something specific to your code that leads to one of the regions not working. If you could add a code snippet to your question, that'd probably help tracking the issue down.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I dont know why it does not work before, but now I changed to one Beacon manager, it works fine.

Comment: BTW, I use major and minor to location one beacon in each region, thus I thought one beacon manager will only listen for one beacon. But it seems not to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion, these should be only one beacon manager to manage all beacon.

And if you have beacon from same vendor (In your case it is Estimote iBeacons) then I don't think that you need to create more than one region here.

Because all beacons of same vendors have same `proximity UUID`. What is different is its `Major value` and `Minor value`.

So you can differentiate all beacons with its Major and Minor values also there is a `ranging` which can make a further granularity for seperation.

Comment: Thanks. It works with one beacon manager with different regions.